# Error 1609. ASPNET is not valid

Tags: asp.net, iis-7, iis-6, windows-installer, installshield

Out company have a product that is being install through InstallShield. 
When I run the installation on a machine with IIS 6 installed it is working great.
But, when I am trying to install it on a machine with IIS 7 install I get:

> **Error 1609.An error occurred while applying security settings. ASPNET is
>   not a valid user or group. This could
>   be a problem with the package, or a
>   problem connecting to a domain
>   controller on the network. Check your
>   network connection and click Retry, or
>   Cancel to end the install. **

what am I doing wrong ? what do I need to change on the installation (or on the installed machine).

Thanks,
Ben

Comment: Install sheild might have made some changes in web.config which are applicable to IIS6 only , you might check it.

Comment: Wasn't ASPNET the account used for running IIS 6 in IIS 5 Isolation Mode? Isn't it NETWORK SERVICE / AppPoolIdentity instead on IIS 7 ?

Answer (score 2):

It is becase you don't have a ASPNET user. You have 2 choices you can either manaually create this user for the purpse of running this package or you can install .net framework 1.1 and then reinstall or reregister the version of .net you intend to run your apps with.

Answer (score 1):

Run the following command to fix this issue:

```
aspnet_regiis –i
```

This is usually available in the .NET Framework installation path. If you use .NET 2.0, for example, the whole path would be:

```
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\aspnet_regiis -i
```

More information about the `aspnet_regiis` command is [available here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k6h9cz8h%28v=vs.80%29.aspx).

Comment: thanks for your help. but I already tried it with no success. other thoughts

Comment: In that case, we'll need more information on the InstallShield setup scripts to diagnose this.